# Regex to match text between 9 space characters

Tags: regex

I'd like to capture the text between a fixed number of 9 spaces from a text that looks like this: [Demo](http://regexr.com/672m9)

```
     (LD4377) Masinuta clasica din lemn tractor - albastru             1                                                              buc                  3             15.00       45.00                  8.55         - Little Dutch
```

What I want to extract: `(LD4377) Masinuta clasica din lemn tractor - albastru - Little Dutch`

What I'm using: `\s{9}((?:(?:[a-z0-9A-Z\-\/()])+[ ]{1})+)\s{9}`

Is there a more efficient way to get the desired text? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can unroll the loop first repeating only the character class, and then optionally repeat a non capture group with a leading space.

You can replace `[ ]{1}` with a mere space

```
\s{9}([a-z0-9A-Z\/()-]+(?: [a-z0-9A-Z-\/()-]+)*)\s{9}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADYykD/1)